# Copy one individual file with its parent folder / full path

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to use PowerShell to copy individual files from an array, to a destination folder. However, I need to copy each file with its respective source folder as well. Not the entire contents of that folder, but just the folder and the file. For example:

```
Copy-Item -Path \\SERVER\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT -Destination E:\TEMP
```

Now obviously, this will bring over that file, but that's it. I would need for it to bring over that file and at least the folder it's in, so preferably I'd wind up with this: E:\TEMP\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT. Alternatively, while not perfect, I could also deal with, E:\TEMP\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT. But nothing I'm doing is bringing over the folder/container the file is in, just the file itself and that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the directory structure already exist, you could try this:

```
Get-Item '\SERVER\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT' | 
    Copy-Item -Destination { Join-Path 'E:\TEMP' $_.Directory.Name }
```

If not, you have to save the new directory path in a variable and create it first.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. The folder doesn't already exist in the target, so I'm trying to bring over the file **and** its respective folder into the target folder. I'm trying to run something like the following line before the line you provided, but it's not working for me (of course, because I'm doing something wrong): `Get-Item $file | New-Item { Join-Path 'E:\TEMP' ( Split-Path $_.DirectoryName -Leaf) } -type directory | Out-Null` **--OR--** `Get-Item $file | New-Item E:\TEMP\$_.DirectoryName -type directory | Out-Null` -- ($file is the variable that's coming from what's in the larger array)

Comment: `Split-Path` isn't required here. `$_.Directory.Name` will give you the name of the directory.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the hint, I updated my answer.

Comment: I was eventually able to get this to work, writing more code and using your suggestions. Thank you for the assistance here.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off using [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

```
robocopy \\SERVER\FOLDER1 E:\TEMP FILE.TXT /s
```

If you get the source path as string (or a list of strings) input you could process it like this:

```
'\\SERVER\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT', ... | Get-Item | ForEach-Object {
  robocopy $_.Directory.Parent.FullName E:\TEMP $_.Name /s
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I thought of using Robocopy and did try out a few times, but my biggest challenge there is that Robocopy requires for you to split the file name and its path into two separate inputs for the command.

The files I'm trying to copy are all being individually pulled from a variable array in PowerShell, so they come over to the robocopy command as a full path + filename, i.e. \\SERVER\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT. Robocopy requires for you to split that, so that it winds up being the example you mentioned above, and also going up one folder in the input (to FOLDER1).

Comment: This suggestion looks like it's getting me closer:

`\\SERVER\FOLDER1\FOLDER2\FILE.TXT', ... | Get-Item | ForEach-Object {robocopy $_.Directory.Parent.FullName E:\TEMP $_.Name /s}`

The caveat is when I run this in my code, it looks like it's somehow trying to search or loop through every single folder in the relative path where this file is -- of which there are thousands of folders -- instead of just getting the specific file and the specific folder it's in, ignoring everything else. I'm sure it's, obviously, still something I'm not understanding. (continued in next comment)

Comment: From my array, I'm doing a `foreach` loop, with a split into a new variable, since the paths are all bunched up in the array. Once the variables are split into individual lines, in the code, I'm doing this:

`$file | Get-Item | ForEach-Object {robocopy $_.Directory.Parent.FullName E:\TEMP $_.Name /s}`

Now this works, but again, it loops through all the thousands of folders where the file that I need to copy is coming from, and eventually does copy that one file, but is really slow in doing so as a result.

Comment: With `robocopy` you can either recurse or not recurse. You can't recurse just a little bit. If there's too much cruft you don't want to process you'll have to go with Martin Brandl's suggestion.